# ¿Cómo acceder a elementos de un json?

Tags: javascript, json

Después de llamar a un servicio web, me devuelve estos datos en formato json.

Necesito quedarme con el valor numérico de $value y guardarlo en una variable.
Estoy trabajando con JavaScript. Gracias

Aquí el json:

```
 {"return":{"attributes":{"xsi:type":"xsd:int"},"$value":115822961}}
```

Comment: Hola Norak. Y qué has intentado? por qué ha fallado: errores o el resultado no es el esperado? Un saludo

Comment: Como recibes los datos, puedes agregar el código donde lo obtienes. Te lo pido porque si estas usando jQuery por ejemplo ya debes tener el JSON deserializado en alguna variable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Si lo que te devuelven es una cadena string deberias convertirlo en un objeto para poder acceder al atributo:

```
let objJson = JSON.parse(string)
```

Ahora volviendo a tu caso, teniendo dicha estructura (la organize mejor usando [JsonLint](http://jsonlint.org) para que la estructura y sus niveles sean mas legible):

```
  {
      "return": {
          "attributes": {
              "xsi:type": "xsd:int"
          },
          "$value": 115822961
      }
  }
```

para tener el valor de `$value` solo debes hacer

```
 let value = objJson.return.$value.;
```

normalmente si no hay caracteres extraños se puede acceder a los atributos de un objeto separando por `.` los identificadores, pero para identificadores con carácter especial puedes usar `['clave']` y podrías traer campos con espacios por ejemplo `['mi atributo']` dicho esto las siguientes llamadas son idénticas:

```
 objJson.return.$value;
 objJson['return']['$value'];
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente! muchas gracias porque soy novata y me estaba volviendo loca con este tema. Saludos!